# Email Bounces: Sender address rejected: Domain not found

Tags: email-bounces

I'm getting the error below when sending mail via smtp through google apps mail. Can anyone see why I get this error? As far as I can tell my domain exists!

> THIS IS A WARNING MESSAGE ONLY.
>
> YOU DO NOT NEED TO RESEND YOUR MESSAGE.
>
> Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:
>
> ```
>  a.kozikowski@tutek.pl
> ```
>
> Message will be retried for 2 more day(s)
>
> Technical details of temporary failure: Google tried to deliver your
>   message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain
>   tutek.pl by mx.maxus.pl. [213.241.89.166].
>
> The error that the other server returned was: 450 4.1.8
>   : Sender address rejected: Domain not
>   found

Comment: You really should not have removed the details when you [cross-posted this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14778890/1068283). They were necessary to answer your question.

Comment: Ahhh....I was wondering where you got the information in your response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mail server `mx.maxus.pl` attempted to look up the domain name in the `From:` email address, `aquarius@aquariusprams.co.uk`, and was unable to find it.

This means your recipient's mail server is having trouble resolving domain names correctly, as I was able to look this up successfully.

The problem is with the recipient's mail system, not with your Google Apps setup. If the recipient fixes it before the expiration given in that warning message, then the mail will be delivered. Otherwise you will get a final bounce message after that time.